# Equal height divs based on content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three divs that are next to eachother inside a container div, with varying length content. I would like to make the divs all be the same height, so if one of them have more content than the others, the other two will expand to match the biggest size. The divs all have the same class.

I've tried several ways to make it work, both with js and css without any luck.

No matter how I tried to make it work, it always resulted in several other problems, that were worse, and that I didnt manage to fix either.

I tried using the flex property of display to the container, and flex: 1; on the divs inside. That resulted in the width getting screwed, either to match the longest word inside, or up to sentences.. The divs are all set to be 28% of the width of the container.

I also tried js, with a solution like this, that also didnt work:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var partners = document.getElementsByClassName('partner');
  var maxHeight = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < partners.length; i++) {
    if (partners[i].offsetHeight > maxHeight) {
      maxHeight = partners[i].offsetHeight;
    }
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < partners.length; j++) {
    partners[j].style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content_wrap partner_wrap">
        <a href="link" target="blank_">
            <div class="partner">
                <div class="logo_partner logo_r"></div>
                <p>Some Content</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="link" target="blank_">
            <div class="partner">
                <div class="logo_partner logo_e"></div>
                <p>Some content</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="link" target="blank_">
            <div class="partner">
                <div class="logo_partner logo_s"></div>
                <p>Twice as much content</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <span class="stretch"></span>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.content_wrap {
    max-width: 70%;
    width: 70%;
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    margin: 100px auto 0px auto;
}

.partner_wrap {
    margin: -100px auto 0px auto;
}

.partner {
    width: 28%;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    background-image: url('../img/concrete-seamless.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    padding: 25px 25px 0px 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.partner:hover .logo_partner {
    height: 85px;
    width: 227px;
}

.partner p {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.partner a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}

.logo_partner {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

(+ ".logo_x" with a background image.)

The div with the class logo_s has more content than the other two, and my hope is to get all of them to adjust accordingly to that one, so they all share the same height at all times.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Css grid attempt:

```
    .content_wrap {
  max-width: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: justify;
  -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  margin: 100px auto 0px auto;
}

.partner_wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(28%, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin: -100px auto 0px auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.partner {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  background-image: url('../img/concrete-seamless.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

Comment: How about a grid?

Comment: Tried using grid aswell, can update and post that css in aswell

Comment: Please post your code as a [repro] while paying extra attention to the word **minimal**

Comment: Your Grid code works fine, except for the negative top margin: `margin: -100px auto 0px auto;`. All of your containers are the same height.

Comment: @ralph.m well it kindof works, but the divs are not the same size. The one div with the most content is still larger than the others.. It seems to make the two other divs the same size however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure at 100% to understand the request but check the snippet if that can help.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content_wrap {
  max-width: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: justify;
}

.partner_wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(28%, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.partner {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/600/400');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_wrap partner_wrap">
  <a href="#" target="blank_">
    <div class="partner">
      <div class="logo_partner logo_r"></div>
      <p>Some Content</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" target="blank_">
    <div class="partner">
      <div class="logo_partner logo_e"></div>
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" target="blank_">
    <div class="partner">
      <div class="logo_partner logo_s"></div>
      <p>Twice as much content</p>
      <p>Twice as much content</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```